# How to insert map data to an array of object

Tags: reactjs

I am mapping out item values which is an array

```
const mappedItems = items.map(item => {
return (
   <div key={item.id}>
     <h2>{item.name}</h2>
     <h2>{item.quantity}</h2>
   </div>
)
});
```

What get outputted is like this:

```
Fun Mix
1

Potato Chips
5
```

I am trying to insert the items to my DB from my API, and the structure of the fields is like this:

```
  Items: {
               name: //Since the mapped value of the name is an array how can I store all the mapped names in this name field which is an object
               quantity: //Same for quantity
               },
```

In my backend controller, I am getting the value like this:

```
 const order = new Order({
      Items: req.body.Items,
   });
```

My DB structure where the items are being inserted to is like this

```
  Items: [
        {
             name: { type: String, required: true },
             quantity: { type: Number, default:  },
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Your question needs more clarity, Where do you want to insert and have you tried doing it? What I can assume is you have array field in schema & you want to insert data there by mapping object here at frontend.  If it's the case then it should be at backend logic, you can add that code here.

Comment: @PRABHAT SINGH RAJPUT  I have updated the question, I hope you understand what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this (unless I missunderstood what you are trying to do):

```
const backendItems = items.map(item => {name:item.name, quantity: item.quantity})
```

So in the end, backendItems looks like this with your example:

```
backendItems: [
        {
             name: "Fun mix",
             quantity: 1,
        },
        {
             name: "Potato Chips",
             quantity: 5,
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I think your solution will put all the mapped items at once in each field. But what I want is each of the mapped items should be an object of name and quantity just as the Item array object

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you edit your post, and show a more detailed example of the output please ?

Comment: For instance, what does mapped name mean? Is this just a string, that is a name of one item, or is it an array of string, containing all of the names of the items ?

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope you understand what I am trying to do

Comment: Ok, then my answer is right: in Items, you hold an array of object. Every object contains 2 fields: name and quantity. It is what you want, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes exactly..........

Comment: AH, so does it answer your question ?

Comment: in my DB it shows null for both field

Comment: Could you please then provide a minimal reproducible example please ? In codesandbox for instance. Thank you